# Azure Blob Storage - sp is mandatory. Cannot be empty

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-authentication, azure-sas

I am getting error while trying to upload a file to Azure Blob Storage using SAS link. Its an authentication error complaining about empty sp attribute. The wierd thing is Sp element is present in SAS Url.

It cannot be a permission issue as I am able to upload the file using the same SAS URL using ADF.

**Url**

> BlobEndpoint=https://####.blob.core.windows.net/####?sp=racwdl&st=2021-12-08T01:14:01Z&se=2022-02-28T09:14:01Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=####

**Details of error**

> Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of
> Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
> RequestId:ed57ec28-f01e-00a9-79d2-ebcfc2000000
> Time:2021-12-08T01:22:40.1147833Z Status: 403 (Server failed to
> authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header
> is formed correctly including the signature.) ErrorCode:
> AuthenticationFailed
>
> Additional Information: AuthenticationErrorDetail: sp is mandatory.
> Cannot be empty
>
> Content: `AuthenticationFailed`Server
> failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of
> Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
> RequestId:ed57ec28-f01e-00a9-79d2-ebcfc2000000
> Time:2021-12-08T01:22:40.1147833Zsp
> is mandatory. Cannot be empty
>
> Headers: x-ms-request-id: ed57ec28-f01e-00a9-79d2-ebcfc2000000
> x-ms-error-code: AuthenticationFailed Content-Length: 407
> Content-Type: application/xml Date: Wed, 08 Dec 2021 01:22:39 GMT
> Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

**Code**

```
Stream file = new FileStream(fileToUpload, FileMode.Open);
                var blobServiceClient1 = new BlobServiceClient(endpointString);
                var containerRef = blobServiceClient1.GetBlobContainerClient("dropoff-commissionstatements");
                var blob1 = containerRef.GetBlobClient("TDM_FINAL_102449_13092021_COMMSTMT_AR_TAL_D95337.csv");
                string file_extension = Path.GetExtension(fileToUpload);
                string filename_withExtension = Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload);
                blob1.Upload(file);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try by changing your connection string to something like:

```
BlobEndpoint=https://####.blob.core.windows.net/####; SharedAccessSignature=sp=racwdl&st=2021-12-08T01:14:01Z&se=2022-02-28T09:14:01Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=####
```

For more details, please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string#create-a-connection-string-using-a-shared-access-signature.

Comment: Gaurav - I get this error - No valid combination of account information found.

Comment: I tried again by going through the URL provided by you and its working now. I will upvote your answer