# .Net Framework - Upload Blob using SAS

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-sdk

I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70268870/azure-blob-storage-sp-is-mandatory-cannot-be-empty) but that was for .Net core. Unfortunately, I have to use .net framework to do the same work as ADF does not support custom components in .Net Core.

**Introduction**
I am trying to upload a file to Azure Blob using .net framework SDK. The code is below:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UploadBlobAndUpdateMetadata
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try {
                string storageAccntConnection = "https://*****.blob.core.windows.net/****;SharedAccessSignature=sp=racwdl&st=2021-12-08T01:14:01Z&se=2022-02-28T09:14:01Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=****";
                string blobFilePath = @"*****\\log.20210801.003851.txt";
                string blobContainer = "dropoff-commissionstatements";
                var cloudBlockBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(storageAccntConnection));
                cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFile(blobFilePath);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
            }
            Console.Write("File uploaded to techblobcontainer container");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**
[image]

If I change the connection string to the below, I get 403 Forbidden

https://****.blob.core.windows.net/***?sp=racwdl&st=2021-12-08T01:14:01Z&se=2022-02-28T09:14:01Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=*****

[image]

The problem cannot be in the connection string as I was able to achieve the same with .Net Core.

Comment: Have a look at the [error codes for blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-error-codes): (409) Conflict typically means the blob already exists. You're trying to upload another blob with the exact same name, and it won't let you

Comment: Yeah, I checked it but the blob didnt exist

Answer (score 0):

Considering `CloudBlockBlob` takes the URI of the blob as parameter, please try changing your `storageAccntConnection` to something like:

```
string storageAccntConnection = "https://<account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name e.g. dropoff-commissionstatements>/<blob-name e.g. log.20210801.003851.txt>?sp=racwdl&st=2021-12-08T01:14:01Z&se=2022-02-28T09:14:01Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=****";
```

then your code should work.